# Guice: Creation exception in Junit test class

Tags: java, junit, guice, dropwizard

### Edit: The approach mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/uvzwppi8IyM) worked for me.

I am trying to code a unit test for my Dao class in a dropwizard application.

The initialize method of the application's main class is as follows.

```
public void initialize(Bootstrap<ContentAnalysisConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        GuiceBundle.Builder<ContentAnalysisConfiguration> guiceBundleBuilder = GuiceBundle.newBuilder();
        guiceBundle = guiceBundleBuilder
                .addModule(new ContentAnalysisModule())
                .setConfigClass(ContentAnalysisConfiguration.class)
                .enableAutoConfig(getClass().getPackage().getName())
                .build();
        bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
    }
```

The `module` class for Guice is as follows:

```
public class ContentAnalysisModule extends AbstractModule {

    private DBI jdbi;

    @Provides
    public DBI prepareJdbi(Environment environment, ContentAnalysisConfiguration configuration) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        // setup DB access including DAOs
        // implementing a singleton pattern here but avoiding
        // Guice to initialize DB connection too early
        if (jdbi == null) {
            final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
            jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDatabase(), "mysql");
        }
        return jdbi;
    }

    @Provides
    public AdRequestDao prepareAdRequestDao(DBI jdbi) {
        return jdbi.onDemand(AdRequestDao.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Crawler.class).to(JsoupCrawler.class);
        bind(Detector.class).to(DictionaryBasedDetector.class);
    }
}
```

The `Dao` class is as follows:

```
public interface AdRequestDao {

    @Mapper(AdRequestMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("select * from ref_requests where DATE(updated_at) = :date order by updated_at")
    public List<AdRequest> getRefUrlByDate(@Bind("date") String date);

    void close();

}
```

However when I try to create a Guice Injector from my test class I am getting the following error:
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

```
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in io.dropwizard.setup.Environment. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at io.dropwizard.setup.Environment.class(Environment.java:53)
  at com.flipkart.flap.modules.ContentAnalysisModule.prepareJdbi(ContentAnalysisModule.java:38)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.flipkart.flap.dao.AdRequestDaoTest.createdao(AdRequestDaoTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The code for the test class is as follows:

```
public class AdRequestDaoTest {
    private AdRequestDao adRequestDao;

    @Before
    public void createdao () {
        System.out.println("At Before");
        Injector myInjector = Guice.createInjector(new ContentAnalysisModule());
        this.adRequestDao = myInjector.getInstance(AdRequestDao.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetRefUrlByDate() {
        //this.adRequestDao = adRequestDao;
        String date = Utils.getCurrentDate();
        List<AdRequest> requests = adRequestDao.getRefUrlByDate(date);

        for(AdRequest request : requests) {
            assertEquals(15417220,request.getAffiliateId());
            assertEquals("http://popmp3.in/video/list/5367690",request.getRefUrl());
            assertEquals("2015-08-12 06:00:30",request.getCreatedAt());
            assertEquals("2015-08-17 16:44:20",request.getUpdatedAt());
            assertEquals(12,request.getNoOfRequests());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I believe this might be interesting for some users. Could you provide an answer using the linked code (not just the link) and later accept your answer so everyone can see that this is solved? Modifying the question text with a link is very confusing. Its also better for your karma :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your test may not be providing an Environment; Guice is complaining that it doesn't know how to create one.

You may need to create a Module for your test that provides Environment and any other dependencies of ContentAnalysisModule.